# Extracting a column using $ sign return Null

Tags: r, dplyr, rsqlite

The following SQLite database is a tiny replica of a huge database that i'm working on.

```
library(RSQLite)
library(inborutils)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
col1 <- c(1:20)
col2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", 
"L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T")
col3 <- c(21:40)
database <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "testDB.sqlit")
table1 <- tibble(col1, col2, col3)
dbWriteTable(database, "testDBtable", table1)
bd <- tbl(database, "testDBtable")
```

I want to extract a column and factor the values. I'm facing a problem with the extraction process, either because I'm missing something or i haven't understand the process as whole.

The following code is working to extract one column but very slow (When i use it on my database not on this tiny replica): -

```
>pull(bd, col2) 
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" 
"Q" "R" "S"
[20] "T"
```

whereas this code return Null: -

```
>bd$col2
NULL
```

Any idea why this returns Null?

I want to use the code as follows: -

```
bd$col2 <- ordered(bd$col2, levels=lvl.100260, labels=lbl.100260)
```

as this code is awfully slow: -

```
bd %>% 
 pull(col2) %>% 
  ordered(
    ., 
    levels = lvl.100260, 
    labels = lbl.100260
 )
```

Especially as a huge number of the same code must be run.

Comment: You should include a reproducible example.

Comment: The database is the only part I omitted or can't share as it is HUGE ~30 Gb  Otherwise I would be more than have to share what is wanted.

Comment: The first step in putting together a minimal reproducible example is minimizing it.  It's really unlikely that the full 30 Gb of data is needed to trigger the problem.  First try to put together a tibble that shows it, completely skipping the database.  If you can't do that, then make up a tiny database and demonstrate using that.

Comment: Just added the requested example.

Answer (score 0):

You use a package `inborutils` that is not on CRAN.  I ran your code without it, so the results below might not match yours.

The problem is that `bd` does not have an element called `col2`:

```
> names(bd)
[1] "src" "ops"
```

It has class

```
[1] "tbl_SQLiteConnection" "tbl_dbi"              "tbl_sql"              "tbl_lazy"            
[5] "tbl"
```

so it's not based on a dataframe, it needs to go to the database to extract data.  I think it's possible to override the `$` operator, but I suspect if you did, you'd find `bd$col2` just as slow as `pull(bd, col2)`.

For the more general question of how to speed it up, I don't think there are any easy answers.  Probably you want to work with real dataframes (or even better, matrices) for speed, but it sounds as though you'll run into memory limitations if you try to convert the whole database at once.  The general advice would be to profile your code to find the bottlenecks, and think about how to improve them.

Comment: So you mean that the problem is because the bd is not a "DataFrame" ? Cause bd has col2 as you can see below.

> bd
# Source:   table<testDBtable> [?? x 3]
# Database: sqlite 3.36.0 [C:\Users\dr_og\testDB.sqlit]
    col1 col2   col3
   <int> <chr> <int>
 1     1 A        21
 2     2 B        22
 3     3 C        23

Comment: Look at `str(bd)` and you'll see what's really there.  If you just print `bd`, you'll use the print method for one of those classes.  If you use `bd$col2`, you'll use the `$` method, but it looks as though there isn't one specific to those classes and you get the default one.